# Can we think of a .deb file in Linux as equivalent to a .msi file in Windows? What are the differences?

Tags: windows, deb, debian-installer, microsoft-installer

.deb files in Linux have been quite confusing since I was introduced to Linux. Is it safe to think of the .deb files as being similar to .msi files in Windows?...are there any problems in this analogy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are going to do with this '*analogy*'?

Comment: I'd say *deb* are more like *cab* files, being containers containing a compressed group of files.

Comment: One difference would be that a `.deb` file contains names and versions of other packages that the package depends on. This allows a software installer such as `apt` to install dependencies (if possible) and thus maintaining integrity.

Comment: I am quoting the Debian Administrators Handbook here: A Debian package is an archive containing all the files required to install a piece of software. It is generally a file with a .deb extension, and it can be handled with the dpkg command. Also called a binary package , it contains files that can be directly used (such as programs or documentation). On the other hand, a source package contains the source code for the software and the instructions required for building the binary package. (https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.book-structure.html)

Comment: There are enormous problems with the analogy. Classic apples-to-oranges. Let go of using .msi files as the measurement , then your understanding of how .deb packages and apt/dpkg work will come more easily.

Comment: as @user535733 mentioned, I also find it very important to learn the philosophy of how linux is handling package management. Once you grasp the principle a new world will unfold. This philosophy is covering gaps that you did not even know that existed when using windows...

Comment: Discussion at Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103531/256762

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer and another one here: https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.book-structure.html and here: https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/debian-packaging.html I can say that the analogy is not that bad.
On the other hand, as mentioned in the comments, the `.deb` file is stating the dependencies to other packages, thing which has to do with the granularity of the linux package management, while the `.msi` files are, let's say, self sufficient: you only need to install it in order to have the program running.